# JTable does not show up

Tags: java, swing, jtable, springlayout

I'm a Java beginner and I'm using Eclipse to create an simple app with a `SpringLayout` and a button inside. I call that button 'btnTABLE' and here is its `actionPerformed` code:

```
btnTABLE.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                "Last Name",
                "Sport",
                "# of Years",
                "Vegetarian"};

        Object[][] data = {
                {"Kathy", "Smith",
                 "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
                {"John", "Doe",
                 "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
                {"Sue", "Black",
                 "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
                {"Jane", "White",
                 "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
                {"Joe", "Brown",
                 "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
            };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    }
});
```

But when i click that button, the table doesn't show up.

Comment: Hm, do you add it to some frame/dialog? These components cannot appear on their own but within a container.

Comment: I think its container is JScrollPane, is it right ?
I also add this at the end:     frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
but nothing changes #.#

Comment: *I think its container is JScrollPane, is it right ?* Yes it is, but this scroll pane is not added to any container so @rlegendi's point still valid. On the other hand while you can add components to containers dynamically (i.e.: by pressing a button), those are tipically placed *before* making the top-level container (window) visible.

Comment: thanks for reply.  i've found my problem, it's SpringLayout. i have a table added into a scrollpane, the table shows up when i put Scrollpane into frame but it doesn't when putting it to SpringLayout. I wonder why ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> simple app with a SpringLayout

A SpringLayout is a complicated layout manager. You can' just use simple code like:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
```

When using SpringLayout you need to specify a few constraints. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use SpringLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) for more information.

Also, if you are attempting to dynamically add a component to a visible GUI then the basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

I would suggest you should be using a different layout manager for the panel.

Comment: thank so much, you answer is very useful. I wonder how to add a scrollpane into a SpringLayout. thanks